# how to decode base64 to image from api flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I understood what my problem is, so I have a question: how properly decode base64 to image? Now My code is like this and I got the error.

```
   Future<void> _download() async {
    var inputedStartTime = DateTime.parse(startTimeController.text);
  var mili = inputedStartTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000;
  var startTime = mili.toInt();
  print(startTime);
    final _url =
        "https://securelink/cameras/874/snapshot/$startTime/";

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(_url));

    final imageName = path.basename(_url);

    final appDir = await pathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    final localPath = path.join(appDir.path, imageName);
    
    final imageFile = File(localPath);
    await imageFile.writeAsBytes(base64Decode(_url));

    setState(() {
      _displayImage = imageFile;
    });
  }
```

when i run my code it return the error:  Unhandled Exception:

```
FormatException: Invalid character (at character 6)
E/flutter (19559): https://securelink/cameras/874/snapshot/1644496620/
```

Comment: @pskink it returns null, but when I paste the link to the browser I get the image as I expected

Comment: @pskink just cookies. I am trying also to do smth like this, and i get print(base64.encode(response.bodyBytes)); and it only converts to base64, right? When i print body, the I get thename of my image

Comment: @pskink when i use print(responce.headers) I see in logs my cookie